# runtime error after trying to set parameters in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to set parameters, I'm getting the following error:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'`

`what():  Node has already been added to an executor.`

I was able to get around this problem by creating another node within my constructor.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to get around this problem.  Please look at the code snippet below.  Thanks.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
     rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<TestParameter>());
     rclcpp::shutdown();
     return 0;
 }
```

test_parameter.hpp

```
class TestParameter : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  TestParameter();
  ~TestParameter();

  void subCB();
  void saveParamToServer();

private:
  rclcpp::SyncParametersClient::SharedPtr parameters_client_;
  rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>::ConstSharedPtr test_sub_;

};
```

test_parameter.cpp

```
TestParameter::TestParameter()
    : Node("TestParameter")
{

  parameters_client_ = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node>(this));

  test_sub_ = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>(
      "testsub", std::bind(&TestParameter::initialPoseReceived, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

TestParameter::~TestParameter()
{
}

void TestParameter::subCB()
{
  this->saveParamToServer();
}

void TestParameter::saveParamToServer()
{
  parameters_client_->set_parameters({
      rclcpp::Parameter("x", 0),
      rclcpp::Parameter("y", 0),
  });
}
```

To fix this issue, I created another node for parameters within my constructor.

```
 test_node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("TestNode");
 parameters_client_ = std::make_shared<rclcpp::SyncParametersClient>(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node>(test_node));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303837/runtime-error-after-trying-to-set-parameters-in-ros2/) by [mpanah](https://answers.ros.org/users/37607/mpanah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-09-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ahoy, Matey!

It appears that we be a missing something in your code example, because the error `what(): Node has already been added to an executor.` should only occur if you add your node to an `rclcpp::Executor` and/or pass it to `rclcpp::spin` more than once. From the code you've shared I only be able to spot it being used like this in one place, i.e. when you do `rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<TestParameter>());`.

I do have some other comment for yer, however:

- Store ye node, do this instead `auto n = std::make_shared<TestParameter>(); rclcpp::spin(n);`
- Ye don't need a `rclcpp::SyncParametersClient` to change parameters on yer own node, just use `rclcpp::Node::set_parameters` (or a similar method), see: http://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#a7d8af4dc449c7130ccc396814b86c14d

(btw, it's talk like a pirate day: https://discourse.ros.org/t/answer-ros-questions-like-a-pirate-day-2k18/6058)

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2